# Turn list of dictionaries into pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I have a list of dictionaries of stock tickers and dates that looks like the below. I'd like to make a pandas dataframe with the ticker on the left and the date on the top. How can I do that?

```
[{'GOOG': [{'01-10-2018': '0.08388400'}, {'01-11-2018': '0.08787100'}]}, 
{'AAPL': [{'01-10-2018': '0.01660500'}, {'01-11-2018': '0.01715700'}]}]
```

Comment: can you post your desired data set?

Comment: Not sure how to post the pandas table, but ideally it has the tickers on the left and dates on the top. I've tried numerous data frame commands and cannot get them to work

Comment: Are you sure you want the columns to be dates? I'd think you'd want the tickers as column headers, and the dates as an index... AAPL's stock ticker isn't going to change any time soon, and days change, well, daily.

Comment: For future reference, people on SO are generally more willing (and likely) to help if you share the code you've already tried, and explain where you are having trouble. It shows them that you have at least put in the effort to solve it yourself, and aren't just asking someone to do it for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need to reshape your input data into something that's more `pandas` friendly. Here's one way:

```
import pandas as pd

# sample data
l = [
    {'GOOG': [{'01-10-2018': '0.08388400'}, {'01-11-2018': '0.08787100'}]}, 
    {'AAPL': [{'01-10-2018': '0.01660500'}, {'01-11-2018': '0.01715700'}]}
]

# make it into a dictionary (assumes that your symbols are distinct)
temp_d = {ticker: d[ticker] for d in l for ticker in d}

# combine the inner dictionaries, keyed by date
final_d = {
    ticker: {date:x[date] for x in temp_d[ticker] for date in x} for ticker in temp_d
}


# make it into a dataframe
df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(final_d, orient='index')
```

Output:

```
>>> print(df)

      01-10-2018  01-11-2018
AAPL  0.01660500  0.01715700
GOOG  0.08388400  0.08787100
```

And for reference, here is what `temp_d` and `final_d` look like:

```
>>> print(temp_d)

{'AAPL': [{'01-10-2018': '0.01660500'}, {'01-11-2018': '0.01715700'}],
 'GOOG': [{'01-10-2018': '0.08388400'}, {'01-11-2018': '0.08787100'}]}

>>> print(final_d)

{'AAPL': {'01-10-2018': '0.01660500', '01-11-2018': '0.01715700'},
 'GOOG': {'01-10-2018': '0.08388400', '01-11-2018': '0.08787100'}}
```

There are other ways to do this, but the main thing is to reformat your input so that it's compatible with one of the *many* `pandas` constructors.

**Update**

Building on @Evan's comment on the OP, the more sensible (probably) way to do this is to have the tickers as the columns and the dates as the rows. If you changed your mind and wanted to do it that way instead, it's a simple parameter change:

```
df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(final_d, orient='columns')
```

Which prints as:

```
                  AAPL        GOOG
01-10-2018  0.01660500  0.08388400
01-11-2018  0.01715700  0.08787100
```

Comment: `NameError: name 'd' is not defined` for your solution, line 13 (`final_d` def).

Comment: Sorry that was a cut and paste error. It should be fixed now. Thanks for pointing it out. I tried to change the variable names to be more meaningful in the post and I missed one of them.